# How do I count the total number of unique strings from a file using linux

Tags: linux

In `File1`:

```
OrderChange[a.1],partition=ORDER
OrderChangeResponse[2.b],partition=ORDER
```

I used below cmd getting output as 2 but it should be 1 as OrderChange in above file is 1.

```
cat File1|grep -i "OrderChange"|grep -i "ORDER"|wc -l
```

Comment: Could you give more detail about what your input and output formats are, and what you're trying to do? In `grep -i "OrderChange"|grep -i "ORDER"` the second `grep` does nothing since "order" is a substring of "orderchange".

Comment: Input format is File1 output should be like in below format
OrderChange 1 ORDER
OrderChangeResponse 1 ORDER

Comment: So you want to know how many occurrences of each "first" word there are? Each first word and each part after `=` together? Each complete line?

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Let me more clear here.Here is File1 containing 4 lines
OrderChange[a.1],partition=ORDER
OrderChangeResponse[2.b],partition=ORDER
WOChange[a.1],partition=LOG
Message[2.b],partition=LOG

Need output as below 
OrderChange 1 ORDER

But when i run cat File1|grep -i "OrderChange"|grep -i "ORDER"|wc -l getting OrderChange 2 ORDER

Comment: cat File1|grep -i "\bOrderChange\b"|grep -i "ORDER"|wc -l this will help me to solve this thanks user000001

Answer (score 2):

To search only whole words, with some `grep` implementations you can use the word boundary operator `\b`:

```
$ grep -i "\bOrderChange\b" file
OrderChange[a.1],partition=ORDER
```

Some `grep`'s also support a `-w` option for that:

```
$ grep -wi OrderChange file
OrderChange[a.1],partition=ORDER
$ grep -cwi OrderChange file
1
```